# Updating the page with Ajax

Tags: ajax, ejs

after i submit a form with Ajax and i have the result back ... i need to update my EJS tag with this new data.

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: function(result){
    ........
 console.log(result)
 }
```

and in my EJS file i have this code:

```
<% if(test.type =='type_1' ) { %> type 1 information <% } %>

<% if(test.type =='type_2' ) { %> type 2 information <% } %>
```

so if the user change the input to type 2 i need to update my page and show the user the information of type 2 without refreshing the page